# How to create bullet point inside JSTL code

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have a requirement to create the HTML bullet point text inside JSTL code like

The paragraph text

- text example 1

- text example 2

I'm using code

```
<div>
     <p>${otherTest}</p>                    
     <c:forEach items="${result}" var="currentItem" varStatus="stat">
    Tips ${stat.index +1 }: ${currentItem}<br> 
    </c:forEach>

</div>
```

Here result contains the paragrapth text and example text. How can I achive this?

Comment: how paragraph and example text are separated in result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
    <c:set var="data"
    value="this is title text\n this is the headigs text: \n 
 this is the tip tesxt1 \n this is the tip text2\nthis is the tip text3"></c:set>
 <c:set var="newline" value="\n" />
<c:set var="dtatPart" value="${fn:split(data, newline)}"></c:set>
<c:set var="limit" value="${fn:length(fn:split(data, newline))}"></c:set>

<p>
    <i>Tip: ${dtatPart[0]}</i>
</p>
<br>
${dtatPart[1]}
<ul>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="2" end="${limit-1}">
        <li>${dtatPart[i]}</li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: <c:set var="data"
 value="this is title text\n this is the headigs text: \n 
 this is the tip tesxt1 \n this is the tip text2\nthis is the tip text3"></c:set>
 <c:set var="newline" value="\n" />
<c:set var="dtatPart" value="${fn:split(data, newline)}"></c:set>
<c:set var="limit" value="${fn:length(fn:split(data, newline))}"></c:set>

<p>
 <i>Tip: ${dtatPart[0]}</i>
</p>
<br>
${dtatPart[1]}
<ul>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="2" end="${limit-1}">
  <li>${dtatPart[i]}</li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>